# Demonstrate the existence of following limit using squeeze theorem

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \sqrt[3]x \cdot e^\frac{-y^2}{x^2}$$

I have not idea what function to put in the inequality.
Some aid?

Comment: The challenge here is to show that the limit is the same no matter how $(x,y)$ approaches the origin.

Answer (score 4):

$$\left|\sqrt[3] xe^{-\frac{y^2}{x^2}}\right|\leq \left|\sqrt[3]x\right|\underset{(x,y)\to (0,0)}{\longrightarrow} 0$$

Comment: I have thought this solution but I was not so sure because it means that the exponential function is always < 1.

Comment: Since $-\frac{y^2}{x^2}\leq 0$ for all $x,y$ and that $x\longmapsto e^x$ is increasing, you will have $e^{-\frac{y^2}{x^2}}\leq e^0=1$ for all $x,y$. No doubt is possible here :-)